# Firebase Leaderboard JSON

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real-time database, I am trying to make a country leaderboard based on points with JSON, however, when I convert objects to JSON it returns undefined.

**Heres my code:**

```js
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref('countries');
userRef.orderByChild("points").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    const json2 = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())
    console.log(json2)
    var tr;
    var rank = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + rank + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json2[i].country + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json2[i].points + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
        rank = rank + 1;
    }
});
```

**JSON:**

```json
{
   "Spain": {
      "country": "Spain",
      "points": 201
   },
   "Sweden": {
      "country": "Sweden",
      "points": 101587
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop `for (var i = 0; i < json2.length; i++) {` iterates over the `json2` string, which is probably not what you want.

Instead, you'll want to loop over `snapshot` and then extra the individual values from that:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref('countries');
userRef.orderByChild("points").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var tr;
    var rank = 1;

    snapshot.forEach((countrySnapshot) => {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + rank + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().country + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + countrySnapshot.val().points + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
        rank = rank + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright, Also, Do you know what I would do to sort the points highest to lowest?

Comment: Results are always returned from Firebase in ascending order. Easiest for you is to reverse them client-side, for example by calling `prepend` instead of `append`.